# Identifying outliers in XY data

Tags: statistics

I'd like some help in finding a simple mathematical way of identifying outlying data points amongst a set. The points are likely to be within the range of values for X and Y but not when considered together on the plane of the plot.

Here's an example that I've put together using real data but I've manually created the outliers to represent a typical case.
[image]

The data is in red and my code will separate the upper and lower segments and then sort them. Occasionally, for reasons I won't bother you with, data points that should lie in one batch will appear in the other. Since it is only one or two points out of many it is likely to be more efficient for me to null the outliers than try to develop alternative code to prevent the problem in the first place.

Later on, the two batches are used in the fitting of polynomials to represent the upper and lower portions of the original data. Sometimes the polynomials are sufficiently distorted to tell me that there's been a problem with outliers. However, rather than rely on the polynomial as a method for identification I'm hoping there's a way I can do it before the curve fitting stage is reached.

I thought there might be a way of using the mean and standard deviation of the X and Y values to identify the outliers, but they aren't outliers if the X and Y means and standard deviations are considered independently. Perhaps there's a way of considering them together in combination? Or some way of looking at the data as a cluster or trend and defining the outliers that way?

I'd be grateful for any help.

Regards, Simon.

Comment: What kind of analysis do you plan to perform? Why do you want to identify outliers?  For example, if you will regress Y on X, then you might use standard outlier detection methods to identify outliers among the residuals.

Comment: Hi @BruceET. A 3rd order polynomial is fitted to the data (regression of Y on X) so that hysteresis and gradient information can be extracted. As I said above, at this point I don't have the polynomial and so there are no residuals at this time. Also, without removing the outliers they will contribute to the polynomial and that's what I'm trying to avoid.